# Exception is thrown when trying to concatenate a character to char*

Tags: c++

Following is my code to create char* _strbuf. It will be created but zero space will be assigned to it in the memory

```
StringBuffer::StringBuffer() {     
    char* _strbuf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*_length);
}

private:
    char* _strbuf;  //buffer to store the original string
    int _length=0;
```

Now, here is an append function which will simply append (concatenate) a character to this char* by reallocating it a new space

```
void StringBuffer:: append(char c) {
    _length++;
    _strbuf = (char*)realloc(_strbuf, sizeof(char) * _length);
    cout << "\n";
    cout << _strbuf;
    _strbuf[_length-1] = c; //exception thrown here        
    cout << _strbuf;
}
```

There is some kind of a problem with assignment. 
PS: Im trying to implement StringBuffer class. No `std::string`s allowed

Comment: just an FYI there is no reason to multiply `_length` by `sizeof(char)`.  `sizeof(char)` will always be 1.

Comment: Guessing: Zero termination, check return values!

Comment: What an unholy mix of C and C++...

Comment: @SergeyA I do not know how to reallocate the space..!! I did try using new but it only appended garbage values

Comment: @puffles, you need to allocate new space, copy the old buffer into new space and delete old buffer.

Comment: @SergeyA Hence, the `realloc()`?

Comment: @Barry, I still do not see a reason to use it, there is no benefit over manual buffer management rather than saving 2 lines of code. But it pulls in unholly casts, and code becomes the sore in the eye.

Comment: @SergeyA You don't see a reason to use one line of code that isn't error-prone, over several lines of code, making sure you allocate and deallocate as appropriate? Really? Plus `realloc` doesn't necessarily have to copy.

Comment: @Barry, you are blowing it out of proportions. Yes, I see no reason to use `realloc()` rather than a proper C++-specific memory management techniques, even if it saves you exactly two lines. As for error-proning - this is true red herring. Nothing is more error-prone than C-style casts.

Comment: @Barry - actually, `realloc` is quite error prone: most uses of it are simply wrong. The code here demonstrates the problem: if the runtime can't expand the memory block in place and can't allocate a new block it leaves the old data alone and returns a null pointer. As written, when that happens this code loses the old data block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write:

```
StringBuffer::StringBuffer() {    
    char* _strbuf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*_length);
}
```

That doesn't `malloc` the *member* `_strbuf`. That `malloc`s a *local variable* named `_strbuf`, which happens to have the same name as your member `_strbuf`. But the member remains uninitialized.

So when you then do:

```
_strbuf = (char*)realloc(_strbuf, sizeof(char) * _length);
```

This fails, since `_strbuf` wasn't previously allocated by `malloc()`.

To fix that, just change what you're doing in your constructor from a declaration to an assignment:

```
StringBuffer::StringBuffer() {    
    _strbuf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*_length);
}
```

which can be moved into a mem-initializer-list to avoid any confusion:

```
StringBuffer::StringBuffer()
    : _strbuf((char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*_length))
{ }
```

---

Once you fix that, strings in C/C++ have to be null-terminated. You're not accounting for that anywhere. You need to ensure that the last char in your buffer is always `\0`.

Comment: Fixed it...!! But it is now appending some garbage values as well.

Comment: @puffles You're not null-terminating your strings anywhere.

Comment: Above mentioned are the only two functions I'm using with only those lines of code @Barry

Comment: @puffles Right, and neither of them ensure that `_strbuf` is null terminated.